# Insulin Prices Particularly Novolog

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

I would like to data scrape a reliable source where I can get real time data about insulin prices.  I am using Python's BeautifulSoup and shoving the results into a SQL database that has the columns of Date, Vendor, and Retail Price. Or are there already reliable open data sources about this topic? I was currently reading reports about insulin trends and the people have these graphs; however, I often question where did they get their data.

Comment: where have you looked?

Comment: @albert I did this search on Google 'insulin prices usa 2020 database "database"'. It pointed me to some private databases. I was wondering if there were some open ones.

Comment: try adding open data to it. i just did and first two results are open data.

Comment: @albert I might need to see a url because I tried 'insulin prices usa 2020 open data "database"', and 'insulin prices usa 2020 open data "open data"' and they both did not work been trying for 2 days already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these out, not real time, one updated monthly and the other yearly:

1. [National Average Drug Acquisition Costs](https://data.medicaid.gov/Drug-Pricing-and-Payment/NADAC-National-Average-Drug-Acquisition-Cost-/a4y5-998d)
2. [Medical Expenditure Panel Survey](https://www.meps.ahrq.gov/mepsweb/)

NADAC gives you the wholesale prices I think. MEPS is a great source but requires a lot of digging and cross referencing different parts of the survey on a common key. As far as open data those are the best I have found for expense estimating. Also check out open FDA.

Good luck!